# Insert code with gray background (in a paper)

Tags: overleaf, code

I am writing a paper on blockchain and I saw a style that I really liked. It is to put the code on a black background (my sheet is divided into two columns). The problem is that it is the first paper I am writing and I don't know very well how to put the code with the background in gray (besides, it would have to have the same width as the column).

I put a picture in case it can be of help:

[image]

I tried to execute this code (it's just an example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % For dummy text

\lstset{
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0.5pt,sharp corners]
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, gobble=12]
    function calculateFitness() public{
        for(uint j = 0; j < population.length; j++){
            uint[] memory assignments = new uint[](agents.length);
            for(uint i = 0; i < population[j].getGenesLenght(); i++){
                uint[] memory pref;
                // We get preferences for current agent
                (,,pref) = agents[population[j].getGene(i)].getAgentInfo(); 
                assignments[population[j].getGene(i)] += pref[i];
            }
            population[j].setFitness(getMin(assignments));
        } 
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

and then I got few questions:

1.- How could I fix the text so that it does not stand out of the box?
2.- It seems LaTeX doesn't have Solidity languague (Ethereum blockchain) so I'd like to put different colors (like the pic above, the first one) but I can't write `\textcolor{blue}` inside the `listings` labels.
3.- I don't understand why the first word has been removed: the code starts with *"function calculateFitness()..."*, but the pic only shows *"calculateFitness()..."*

Comment: You specified `gobble=12`, so the first twelve characters of each line is eaten.

Comment: Oh, true! My bad.

Comment: try also adding the `basicstyle=\small` key to `lstlisting`, this will set the code in smaller font, making it possible to fit more in a fixed width. If it still is too wide: it is your job to format the input in a way that works with the syntax of the language and display nicely. For python it can be a it annoying. But for braces-semicolon languages like solidity, you can insert line breaks, right? Alternatively you can try breaking out of two-column mode and have the code listing be full width.

Comment: As for the package not supporting solidity, please look at the manual (section 3.2) https://ctan.org/pkg/listings?lang=en If you have a list of the common language keywords, making it known to the package takes just a few lines of code.

Comment: that really helped, tysm. What about the syntax color? Can I change the color inside `lstlisting`?

Comment: See section 1.3 of the manual. You can change the font size/style for the basic code, as well as specified how keywords and comments will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i finished it already! By the way, last question: is the first font `\texttt` (if we look at the first pic code)? Looks like similar to that one but i'm not sure..

Comment: There is a [big collection of typewriter fonts](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html) available for LaTeX if you want to choose your favourite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here's one way to do it using the `listings` package for typesetting the code and the `tcolorbox` package for the gray box (which just happens to be the default colour for a `tcolorbox`). Featuring some hastily written example code in python.
There is much more that you could do with both `listings` and `tcolorbox` to control how the output looks but this should get you started.
This also works if you use the `twocolumn` option but be careful as the code doesn't wrap automatically so is likely to overrun into the next column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % For dummy text

\lstset{
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        boxrule=0pt,
        sharp corners
    ]
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=python, gobble=12]
            def fib(n: int):
                if n < 0:
                    raise ValueError
                else if n == 0 or n == 1:
                    return 1
                else:
                    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between loading `listings` and `tcolorbox` and just loading `tcolorbox` with the `listings` library?

Comment: For the purpose of this I've just tried and both work the same, but I wasn't even aware that `listings` could be loaded in that way before this comment so I'm probably not the person to ask.

Comment: No worries, I was just wondering

Comment: @Willoughby I updated the post and maybe you could help me a little more. I really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.